# Center Background colour using css

Tags: html, css

I am planning to add colour to the center of the html page. I have tried this:

## My html file

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="v">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## My styles.css

```
#v {
 background: red;
 position: center;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the center of the page"? First try using `background-color` instead of `background`.

Comment: Add width to your div and do margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

You can set a height and a width to the `div` and add a margin like this:

```
#v {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you mean to center an element on the page and then add a background color to that element. Your CSS is not valid although you did come close. if you want to add a background then you need to use background-color instead. If you want to center that element then you can adjust the margin of said element here. is an example that may help.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>center a div and add background color</title>

<style type="text/css">

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 auoto;
}
.centered-element{
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="centered-element">
        <p>this div is centered!</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

what i have done is gave the div that i wanted to center align a margin of 0 auto; this will center align the div. I hope that helped!